# how to add method to python's buildin class and some other packages class?

Tags: python

I frequently received data that has one single value wrapped in a class, like `{{127.1}}`, or a pandas frame only 1 row x 1 columns and I only need `obj.ix[0][0]`. So my intention is to write a generic function for this like the following.

I am thinking maybe I could do by adding method to each class, so the generic function will not grow longer and longer when I found more and more classes for situations like that.It will be like `obj.getatom1()` where I can provide method to list class, pandas.panels class.

How can I do this to build-in python class, and how to do this if I want to do it to other packages without editing the source directly.

```
def getatom1(obj,failedreturn=None):
    ''' Return the single element from obj and if obj is empty or not a single value wrapped in a class then return the failedreturn
        Case single element list/tuples: {1}, return 1
        Case single element double layer list/tuples: {{1}}, return 1
        Case single pandas.datapanel element: obj.ix[0].ix[0][0]
        Case single pandas.dataframe element: obj.ix[0][0]
        Case single pandas.timeseries element: obj.ix[0]
        Case ...
    '''
```

Comment: One of the easiest ways to do this, as opposed to adding the method to each class, would be using a decorator. Here is some information about decorators: https://wiki.python.org/moin/PythonDecorators

Comment: You cannot add methods to a built-in class; you can only subclass them.

Comment: chepner has a good point. If you are sure that you will keep adding new methods to built-in class, then subclass them and built all your code from that.

Comment: Well most of time the data is received as it is. I can wrapper them. If there is a way to add a method to all related class, that would be ideal.